# How to create text inside marker with google_maps_flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps-api-3, flutter-layout, google-maps-markers

How to implement a marker on Google Maps flutter with text on the marker. Image for reference:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6oqG.jpg

Answer (score 11):

I managed to solve with this method

```
Future<BitmapDescriptor> createCustomMarkerBitmap(String title) async {
        TextSpan span = new TextSpan(
          style: new TextStyle(
            color: Prefs.singleton().getTheme() == 'Dark'
                ? Colors.white
                : Colors.black,
            fontSize: 35.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
          text: title,
        );
    
        TextPainter tp = new TextPainter(
          text: span,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        );
        tp.text = TextSpan(
        text: title.toStringAsFixed(0),
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 35.0,
          color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
          letterSpacing: 1.0,
          fontFamily: 'Roboto Bold',
         ),
        );
    
        PictureRecorder recorder = new PictureRecorder();
        Canvas c = new Canvas(recorder);
    
        tp.layout();
        tp.paint(c, new Offset(20.0, 10.0));
    
        /* Do your painting of the custom icon here, including drawing text, shapes, etc. */
    
        Picture p = recorder.endRecording();
        ByteData pngBytes =
            await (await p.toImage(tp.width.toInt() + 40, tp.height.toInt() + 20))
                .toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);
    
        Uint8List data = Uint8List.view(pngBytes.buffer);
    
        return BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(data);
      }
```

how to use:

```
BitmapDescriptor bitmapDescriptor = await createCustomMarkerBitmap(...);

Marker marker = Marker(
  /*  in addition to your other properties: */
  icon: bitmapDescriptor
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Do you know how to add background color for the text?

Comment: Hi, it was a pleasure. To add the background color of the text you need to create a TextSpan.

   <-- TextPainter painter = new TextPainter(
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    );
    painter.text = TextSpan(
      text: title.toStringAsFixed(0),
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 35.0,
        color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        letterSpacing: 1.0,
        fontFamily: 'Roboto Bold',
      ),
    );-->

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer, thank you!

Comment: @GuilhermeAlvesVieira Please can you tell me, how can I use a custom icon here?

Comment: @Prasath  I did not understand your question

Comment: @GuilhermeA.V.DosSantos I have one icon image(png), I want to get the text inside that icon. Please can you post the answer ?

Comment: @Prasath My post here is to create an icon with customized text. Now what you want is to get the text that is inside an image (png) what do I understand?
you can use a lib to do this: 
- https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_ml_vision

Answer (score 1):

You can either do it manually using Canvas and Painter. Or you could use this package which does the exact same thing asked in the question.

https://pub.dev/packages/label_marker

Just go through the overview once and you can see if it is for you or not. I really hope it helps. And yeah. I made it :)