# How to write text on Flutter Google maps, or more specifically, inside or around polygons?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, text, label, polygon

I have created multiple polygons on Google Maps in a Flutter app. Now I want to write some codes inside or even outside the polygons, for example, poly-101, poly-102, and so on. How can I do that? I see that the Polygon class does not have any label property. There are some options to add text for markers ([How to display text text on google map marker in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70570804/how-to-display-text-text-on-google-map-marker-in-flutter)), but I want to write text for the shapes and not for markers.